# NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

Hi I am attempting to use `sqlalchemy-teradata` to write a pandas dataframe into a Teradata table. Here is the code I am using:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy_teradata

td_engine=create_engine('teradata://'+uid+':'+password+'@'+host+':22/')
```

That comes back with the error above. I have also tried this code as well as I've seen this elsewhere on stackoverflow:

```
engine=create_engine('teradata://'+ uid +':' + password + '@'+ host + '/' + '?authentication=LDAP')
```

I have installed all of the following packages: `sqlalchemy`, `sqlalchemy-teradata`, and `teradatasqlalchemy`.

Has anyone seen this error before? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all check if the packages are installed correctly:

```
$ python
>>> import teradata
>>> import sqlalchemy_teradata
```

Does this give any error messages?

Also, I believe you only need the `sqlalchemy-teradata` package, not `teradatasqlalchemy`.

Comment: Hey codeape, you are right  - import sqlalchemy_teradata throws an error message saying it can't find the module.  However, when i go to execute this command in my conda prompt window: pip3 install sqlalchemy_teradata , it says that the requirement is already satisfied. I'm installing it under a virtual environment called "davesenv"