# NoSuchModuleError: teradata can't load plugin sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, teradata, dialect

I am trying to connect to teradata server to load the data from `pandas DataFrame` to `teradata` using the following create engine

```
 import teradata
 import teradatasql
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
 import sqlalchemy_teradata
 import pandas as pd
 engine=create_engine("teradata://user:pwd@host/DataBase")

 Error:
 NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata
```

I would appreciate your help. 
Can somebody help?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960393/nosuchmoduleerror-cant-load-plugin-sqlalchemy-dialectsteradata

Comment: I tried from the above link only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first check to make sure both of these packages were installed correctly and are imported successfully:

```
 from sqlalchemy import create_engine
 import sqlalchemy_teradata
```

If so, I would restart your Python session - I was getting the same error as you and it finally went away after rebooting.

If you are still running into issues, try this string:

```
td_engine=create_engine('teradata://'+uid+':'+password+'@'+server+'/'+db+'?driver='+driver)
```